# Most efficiently adapting IPEX-MHF1 (Wifi-Card) to IPEX-MHF4 (Antenna)?

Tags: connector, antenna, wifi, signal-integrity, intel

We have a lot trouble with the windows driver our `Intel Wi-Fi 6E AX211` Wifi-cards. It randomly looses connection and [it's a general problem, that a lot of users report](https://community.intel.com/t5/Wireless/description-for-Event-ID-6062-from-source-Netwtw12-cannot-be/td-p/1451766). Intel doesn't seem be able to provide a solution yet.

[image]

Since we have a free `M.2 B-key` slot next to the soldered (yes soldered!) `AX211D2W`, we looked for suitable cards and went with [`Alfa AWM27921U`](https://www.alfa.com.tw/products/awm27921u), which has a male `IPEX-MFH1`/`IPEX-MFH2` antenna-connector. The antenna-cables are `IPEX-MFH4` female and can't be directly plugged into the new Wifi-card.

How to adapt it the best fitting way without loosing too much signal?

Comment: It might be best and easiest to use another Wifi/Bluetooth antenna with the suitable connector. There should be plenty of suitable antennas with the IPEX-MFH2 compatible connectors. Look around on Farnell, Digikey, Mouser, RS etc...

Comment: @citizen actually not. There are none in `M.2 B-key` format.

Comment: the MFH1 are compatible with U.FL (Hirose) so you can look for the antennas with U.FL type terminations instead. There should be plenty !